# Can i use FinalBuilder to set the name of a self extracting exe at Runtime?

Tags: installation, finalbuilder

When using FinalBuilder to package our website, I would like it to be able to set the filename when it creates the file set with a variable somewhere else. So the filename would be Website 1.4.exe

Has anyone got this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to FinalBuilder, so if you could give some more info it would be useful - like which action you're using to create the exe.

Have you tried using project variables? From what I've seen you can use them in most FB actions.

At worst you could use the rename file action:

- create a new project variable ([Tools\Edit Variables\Add]) called Version and give it a default value
- if you need to, you can add a Set Variable action to dynamically set the value of the variable
- add a Rename action

  - set Rename File to the file you want to rename (including path) eg c:\Release.exe
  - set New Name to Release%Version%.exe

That if the Version project variable is set to 1.4, Release.exe will be renamed to Release1.4.exe

Comment: Cheers Ben, exactly what i wanted